# Outlook 2016 - "Check Names" exact match

Tags: regex, microsoft-outlook-2016

When writing a mail I insert a user ID into the address field and use the "Check Names" button to gather its corresponding e-mail address. I get a prompt that Outlook has found the ID multiple times.

E. g. I'm searching for 123, Outlook says it found an e-mail address for 123 but it also displays results for the IDs 1234 and 1235.

How to make Outlook exactly find the corresponding e-mail address for 123?

Operators like `$123*`, `nickname:123` or even `"123"` are not working.

Comment: Unclear, please add more details. And what does regex have to do with it?

Comment: Details added. I thought some may use regular expressions or an operator to do this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way, sorry. This is how Check Names function works and you can't change it. What you can do is to click the "To"/"CC"... button to select the recipient from the address book.